# How do I implement routes?

Tags: routes, 8

How can I implement the most basic route in Drupal 8? What files do I have to write, and which classes do I need to implement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implementing the most basic route in Drupal 8 require:

- The file containing the routing definitions (helloworld.routing.yml)

  ```
  helloworld.hi:
    pattern: '/helloworld'
    defaults:
      _controller: '\Drupal\helloworld\Controller\HelloWorldController::hi'
    requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
  ```
- A controller class that returns a render array or a string (src/Controller/HelloWordCOntroller.php)

  ```
  namespace Drupal\helloworld\Controller;

  class HelloWorldController {
    function hi() {
      return 'Hello world!';
    }
  }
  ```

This is the equivalent of what in Drupal 7 was a `MENU_CALLBACK`. Implementing a local task, or a local action requires other files to be added, differently from Drupal 7, where a local tab would be implemented using the same hook used for a `MENU_CALLBACK`.